# How to implement or customize Fluent UI in the PnP modern web part search v4

Tags: sharepoint-online, pnp

I am using PnP Modern Search Results (v4) to get Local People Results (LocalPeopleResults) in sharepoint.
I want to customize "Edit results template". I want to customize it with Fluent UI. Is it possible to do? If yes, how can i achieve it?

Your valuable support is much appriciated.

Greetings

Answer (score 1):

I'm  not sure if you can customize search result using *Microsoft Fluent UI*.

*Microsoft Fluent UI* is used for creating the controls in web, desktop and team app.

*Modern Search web part* support **Handlebars** to render the search result.

I would recommend to use handlebars to customize search result. You can customize the way you want.

- Handlebars is a simple templating language.
- To get started with handlebars use below link.
- [Handlebars Introduction](https://handlebarsjs.com/guide/#what-is-handlebars)
- Once you have you handlebars template ready, you can apply in modern search web part.
- Refer below article - to check how to apply handlebars template in modern search web part.
- [create-your-first-custom-template](https://microsoft-search.github.io/pnp-modern-search/scenarios/create-your-first-custom-template/)
- Below are sample code for handlebars template.

```
<content id="data-content">
  <style>
    /* Insert your CSS overrides here */
    .example-themePrimary a {
      color: {
         {
          @root.theme.palette.themeprimary
        }
      }
    }

    .myfirstcss{
        font-size: 30px;
        font-weight: 600;
    }

    .icon {
      width: 20px;
      height: 16px;
    }

    ul {
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      flex-wrap: wrap;
    }

    ul li {
      display: flex;
      padding: 8px;

      flex: 1 1 100%;
    }
  </style>

  <div class="template">
    {{#if @root.properties.showSelectedFilters}}
    <pnp-selectedfilters
      data-filters="{{JSONstringify filters.selectedFilters 2}}"
      data-filters-configuration="{{JSONstringify filters.filtersConfiguration 2}}"
      data-instance-id="{{filters.instanceId}}"
      data-operator="{{filters.filterOperator}}"
      data-theme-variant="{{JSONstringify @root.theme}}"
    ></pnp-selectedfilters>
    {{/if}} {{#if @root.properties.showResultsCount}}
    <div class="template--resultCount">
      <label class="ms-fontWeight-semibold"
        >{{getCountMessage @root.data.totalItemsCount
        @root.inputQueryText}}</label
      >
    </div>
    {{/if}}

    <ul class="template--custom">
      {{!-- This div below can be deleted. it is just for showing that is is
      your first template.--}}
      <div class="myfirstcss">This is my custom template!!!!</div>

      {{#each data.items as |item|}} {{#> resultTypes item=item}} {{!-- The
      block below will be used as default item template if no result types
      matched --}}

      <li>
        <pnp-iconfile
          class="icon"
          data-extension="{{slot item @root.slots.FileType}}"
          data-theme-variant="{{JSONstringify @root.theme}}"
        ></pnp-iconfile>
        <span class="example-themePrimary"
          ><a href="{{slot item @root.slots.Path}}"
            >{{slot item @root.slots.Title}}</a
          ></span
        >
      </li>

      {{/resultTypes}} {{/each}}
    </ul>
  </div>
</content>
```